# Strange syntax in a Where clause

Tags: sql-server

The following is a simplied version of a query that a reporting tool is sending to our database. I have never seen this syntax before in the Where clause. Can someone tell me what the brackets are doing? And, I assume the 'd' acts as a date cast?

```
Select
    ch.ContainerID, 
    ch.WorkItemHistoryEventTypeEnumID,
    ch.EventTime,
    ch.ContainerBinName,
    ch.WorkItemSerialNumber,
    ch.Closed
From Wip.vwContainerHistory ch
Where   
   ch.EventTime >= {d '2010-08-09'}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See "Supported String Literal Formats for datetime" section in [MSDN datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) article.

Your `{d 'XXXX-XX-XX'}` is ODBC datetime format. ODBC timestamp escape sequences are of the format: `{ literal_type 'constant_value' }`:

literal_type specifies the type of the escape sequence. Timestamps have three literal_type specifiers:

- d = date only
- t = time only
- ts = timestamp (time + date)

'constant_value' is the value of the escape sequence. constant_value must follow these formats for each literal_type.

```
d > yyyy-mm-dd  
t > hh:mm:ss[.fff]  
ts > yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an ODBC escape sequence for a date type. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

- d = date only
- t = time only
- ts = timestamp (time + date)